# Flow of code in javascript foreach

Tags: javascript

I have this code.Please help me understand it's flow.

```
 <script>

 var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];
 friends.forEach(function (eachName, index){
 console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName); // 1. Mike, 2. Stacy, 3. Andy, 4. Rick?

 });



 </script>
```

First, I see `eachName` variable is defined nowhere.How is it still working?
Second I understand nothing.Please help me.

**EDIT**

I don't understant the function(annonomous) part.

Comment: [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on MDN.

Comment: What kind of programming background do you have? This would help someone explain

Comment: @danielnixon 's link also has an implementation of `forEach()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach()` operates on an iterable object, i.e an array here.

It takes a callback function as an argument `Array.forEach(<callback function>)`

The callback function is executed FOR EACH of the elements in the `Array`

Each time the function is called, the **current element** that is being operated on, is available as the first argument in the callback function.

The `index` of the current element in the `Array` is available as the second argument

The `Array` itself is available as the third argument.

```
Array.forEach(
    function(currentElement, indexOfCurrentElement, Array){
        //do whatever you want with currentElement, indexOfCurrentElement, Array
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a "newbie" and I was also confused by why that worked. Maybe for different reasons, but maybe this will help to whoever is looking at this - I found this same code on Elegant Javascript in an explainer for anonymous functions. The problem has nothing to do with the anonymity of the function here. Took some looking at the specs to see why it spits out what it spits out...simplest explanation:

1) forEach is a special method used for arrays only. (Baffling, but it's not listed here among the methods: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp - where's the *complete* list?)

2) ...but instead of acting like a function that you pass a number or a string to it, forEach expects a function to be given to it within its ()s. The way it wants to be declared is:

```
arrayName.forEach( someFunction(var1, var2, var3) { WHATEVER CODE HERE } )
```

2b) It doesn't have to be an anonymous function either - you can declare a function somewhere else and just pass that to it! In other words:

```
sFunk = someFunction(var1, var2) { CODE! };
arrayName.forEach(sFunk);
```

3) The key to understanding why your code works is figuring out where it's pulling the values for 'eachName' and 'index'...right? When forEach iterates through all the items in your array, it performs a function each time. That function can pull THREE parameters from the array, in this order:

- **the value of the current array item**
- **the numeric index of the current array element**
- **the entire array you're working with, dumped at you as an array**

So if you have an array like:

```
var peaches = ['georgia', 'crab']
```

And you call forEach upon it to print out the three values:

```
peaches.forEach( function(a,b,c) { console.log(a); console.log(b); console.log(c); })
```

You will see:

> georgia
>
> 0
>
> ['georgia', 'crab']
>
> crab
>
> 1
>
> ['georgia', 'crab']

in your console.

For more info, look here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679980(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The symbol `eachName` **is** defined — it's a **parameter** to the callback function. So is `index`.

The runtime calls your function once for each element of the array. It passes in the element value, the index, and the array itself. (Your callback function ignores the third parameter, which is fine.)

JavaScript array indexes start at zero, which is why that `console.log()` line adds `1` to the index value.

The [complete version of what `.forEach()` does is pretty long](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill), but here's a significantly abbreviated (and wrong, for pedagogical reasons) version:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i)
    if (this[i] !== undefined) fn(this[i], i, this);
};
```

The runtime iterates through the array and calls the callback function once for each element.

Comment: Looking at the code and it's output, i can understand what it is doing. YOu are telling me the same thing. I need to know how it is working.

Comment: @Chelsea well I'm not sure I know what it is that's confusing you, unfortunately. What exactly do you want to know? Is it the way that the runtime implements `.forEach()`?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, functions are first class values. Functions can be used where any value could be. Consider the following code (based on your code):

```
var print = function(eachName, index) { 
  console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName); 
}

function print2(eachName, index) { 
  console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName); 
}

var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];
friends.forEach(function (eachName, index){
  console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName);
}); 

friends.forEach(print);
friends.forEach(print2);
```

The first two function definitions of `print()` and `print2()` are just that - they can then be later called like you might expect (i.e. `print("Mike", 1`).

The reason why the code:

```
friends.forEach(function (eachName, index){
  console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName);
});
```

has the function defined in the parameter list of `forEach()` is because you will likely use this function once - to act on elements of the `friends` array. If you had multiple arrays that you wanted to perform similar actions on, you would probably define it like `print()` or print2()` above.

On to `Array.forEach()` - this method expects a function as it's parameter. This is different from most imperative languages (Java, C#, etc.). In my example code, when `friends.forEach(print)` is called, `foreach` calls `print` on each element of `friends`.

Running this code can demonstrate this in action:

```
function print3(element, index, array) { 
  console.log("print3() called");
  console.log(element); 
  console.log(index); 
  console.log(array); 
}

var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];

friends.forEach(print3);
```

Output:

```
print3() called
Mike
0
["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"]
print3() called
Stacy
1
["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"]
print3() called
Andy
2
["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"]
print3() called
Rick
3
["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"]
```